# Codeigniter declaring class level variable in CI_Model class

Tags: php, codeigniter, class-hierarchy

I am new to PHP and Codeigniter, and I am declaring a class level variable which I wanted to access in model class. I'm getting an error that the variable is not defined. Here is my code:

```
 class Country_model extends CI_Model{
    protected $table = 'COUNTRY';
    function __construct()
    { // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function retriveAll(){
        $q = $this->db->from($table)
          ->order_by('ID','ASC')
          ->get();
        if ($q->num_rows()>0){
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared `$table` and accessing in `retriveAll` function. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you access class variables. Try using `$this->table` instead:

```
function retriveAll(){
     $q = $this->db->from($this->table)
          ->order_by('ID','ASC')
          ->get();
     if ($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
      foreach ($q->result() as $row) 
      {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
      return $data;
    }
   }
```

Comment: first sorry for very late response but would like to thank you very much for your response.It actually worked.

Comment: @MehulChauhan Don't worry about that :) If the solution works for you, then, you could mark the answer as "accepted" (using the tick mark under the vote count), so that anyone who sees this question in the future will spot at once the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Access your class variable with $this, like:

```
$this->table
```